# How to display default text if image field value is null in database in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

so I'm creating a report that contains an image field which gets its value from the database. What I'm trying to achieve is to display simple text saying "No image found!" in place of the image if its field value is null or blank in the database. Following is the expression I've written :-

```
=iif(IsNothing(Fields!EmployeeImage.Value) Or Fields!EmployeeImage.Value = "","No image found!",Fields!EmployeeImage.Value)
```

Would really appreciate it if someone can help or guide me in the right direction.

Comment: expression looks like it should work.. what exactly is the issue?

Comment: report executes fine but the image field does not show the text "No image found!", the field is blank with red cross at the top left corner. I need to display the text.

Comment: Remove the expression and if you place the field directly , do any of the images show at all?

Comment: Yes if I remove the expression and simply call the field(=Fields!EmployeeImage.Value) then the images where field value is not null are displayed and shows blanks where the value is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I have done htis in the past, I have stored an image called 'NoImage.png' for exmaple. The noimage image it the typical image you see, something like this.

[image]

Then you just need to point to this image if none is found. I usually do this in the database itself.

Comment: I have made a separate image. Is there a way to point to it using report builder??

Comment: There is no way to change the data image source via an expression (From databse to embedded for example) so you need to get the image into your database and return that image for employees where the image is null, so something like `SELECT EmpID, Emp Name, ISNULL(empImage, defaultImage) as empImage FROM Employees, myDefaultImageTable`